# Using this instead of $scope inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I am trying to follow style guide for angular and there wrote we should use `this` insted `scope`...

[Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Could someone explain me when I am able to use `this`?

Here is my try..... What I am doing wrong?

I am trying to toggle form....
here is my html code:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="formEdit(x)"  ng-if="!x.formEditShow">REPLY</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="formEdit(x)" ng-if="x.formEditShow" >CLOSE</a>
```

With classic `$scope` I would do like this inside my conroller :

```
$scope.formEdit = function(data){
data.formEditShow = !data.formEditShow;
}
```

But with `this` it should look something like this(but don't work):

```
var vm = this;
vm.formEdit = formEdit;

function formEdit(data){
    data.formEditShow = !data.formEditShow;
}
```

Anyone can help me to understand this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using `this`(context) in controller instead of `$scope`, you must use `controllerAs` while defining html on page to access controller variables. Whenever you wanted to use variable bounded to `this` on view you could use `alias` of your controller. Below you can see `vm` is alias of controller.

```
ng-controller="myController as vm"
```

Then while accessing controller method an variable inside `ng-controller` div you need to use alias of your controller like `ng-click="vm.formEdit(x)"`

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="vm.formEdit(x)"  ng-if="!x.formEditShow">REPLY</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="vm.formEdit(x)" ng-if="x.formEditShow" >CLOSE</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain me when I should use `this` and when to use `$scope` ?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic there is case when you have too many nested controller on views which are accessing the scope of parent, so that would make better code on HTML where you could get access to the variable by its alias http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/ And you must go for using `this` inside controller because while migrating code from Angular 1.x to 2.x it would be less effort than you use `$scope`, **$scope** is nothing but an alertanative way to access controller variables & method on HTML..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controller is named **FormController**.

#### First step

The first step is to declare the route (or the `ng-controller` value if you are not using a router) as such:

```
FormController as form // name it semantically instead of a generic name
```

Due to the above configuration, angular will alias as `form` the instances of `FormController`.

#### HTML template

Then adapt your html template according to the alias you gave (*form*). I modified your html to keep only the essential part about the question. We are calling the functions `form.reply` and `form.close`.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="form.reply()">REPLY</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="form.close()">CLOSE</a>
```

#### Controller declaration

According to what we wrote above, our controller should look like that:

```
myApp.controller('FormController', function () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.reply = function () {
        // ...
    }

    vm.close = function () {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Notice the `var vm = this;` line? Theoretically we could get rid of this line, and store the functions `reply` and `close` in the `this` object. But depending of the context, `this` does not refer to the same object. In a callback function `this` would not refer to the controller but to the callback function. That's why we are *caching* the `this` that refers to the controller. We usually name this reference `vm` for *viewmodel*, as a controller *controls* a view.